# Pythonic way to generate a list of possible arrays

Tags: python

Given an array of numbers (e.g. [3, 5, 2]), I'm trying to generate a list of possible arrays that result from adding 1 to one entry in the array: [[4, 5, 2], [3, 6, 2], [3, 5, 3]].

I can get it done by the following, but wondering if there's a more pythonic way to get the result?

```
test = [3, 5, 2]
result = [t.copy() for _ in range(len(test))]
for index, _ in enumerate(result):
    result[index][index] += 1
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean THE list of ALL possible arrays that result from...?

Comment: with range possibility ? @dan-tang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another inline solution with list comprehension:

```
test = [3, 5, 2]
result = [[v+1 if i==j else v for j, v in enumerate(test)] for i in range(len(test))]
```

or, as noticed by [PM 2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring), you can exploit the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0`:

```
result = [[v + (i==j) for j, v in enumerate(test)] for i in range(len(test))]
```

Comment: Nice. There's no need to create `test_range`, though, since it's only used once, so just put it in the list comp. Alternatively, exploit the fact that False is 0 and True is 1, and do `result = [[v + (i==j) for j, v in enumerate(test)] for i in range(len(test))]` although some might complain that that's less readable than your conditional expression.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank's, I'm going to edit ! This kind of comment is why I love StackOverflow  !

Comment: Yeah, it's nice to get the points, but it's also fun to collaborate. And by collaborating we can build great answers that will hopefully not only help the OP but future readers as well.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to do it with a list comprehension:

```
test = [3, 5, 2]   
print [test[:i] + [v + 1] + test[i+1:] for i,v in enumerate(test)]
```

**output**

```
[[4, 5, 2], [3, 6, 2], [3, 5, 3]]
```

Comment: why not use v+1 instead of test[i] + 1

Comment: @Hooting I just tested both with `timeit`: using `v+1` instead `test[i]+1` saves 0.06µs =)

Comment: @Hooting: That's what I _meant_ to do. Honest! :) Thanks for that.